# gcc -D option not doing what I thought it would

Tags: gcc, makefile, asmjit

I'm trying to use AsmJit in a project. This is the makefile I was using:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -D ASMJIT_API -I dep/

test: src/main.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/main.cpp -o test.exe
```

I was getting compiler errors when trying this, so instead I uncommented the line `#define ASMJIT_API` from dep/AsmJit/Config.h, and removed the -D switch from the makefile and everything compiled cleanly. I'm using gcc 4.5.3. Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: Compiler Errors

```
g++ -DASMJIT_API -Idep/ src/main.cpp -o test.exe
In file included from dep/AsmJit/Assembler.h:31:0,
                 from src/main.cpp:1:
dep/AsmJit/Build.h:274:1: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
In file included from dep/AsmJit/AssemblerX86X64.h:36:0,
                 from dep/AsmJit/Assembler.h:51,
                 from src/main.cpp:1:
dep/AsmJit/Defs.h:408:1: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
In file included from dep/AsmJit/DefsX86X64.h:36:0,
                 from dep/AsmJit/Defs.h:423,
                 from dep/AsmJit/AssemblerX86X64.h:36,
                 from dep/AsmJit/Assembler.h:51,
                 from src/main.cpp:1:
dep/AsmJit/Util.h:412:8: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
dep/AsmJit/Util.h:412:8: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
src/main.cpp:6:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
makefile:5: recipe for target `test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: What compiler errors are you getting?

Comment: Basically errors pointing to the fact that something isn't defined correctly. When #define ASMJIT_API is set those other defines work as intended. I'll edit my post to include them if they help at all.

Comment: yes, that would help if you posted more code.

Comment: Well, what's going on at dep/Asmjit/Build.h, line 274 ?

Comment: ASMJIT_API void asertionFailure(const char* file, int line, const char* exp);

Comment: Go look at the pre-processor output with the -E option.
"g++ -E -DASMJIT_API -Idep/ src/main.cpp"  Now go look at the line in the output where "assertionFailure" failure is declared.  Did ASMJIT_API get translated to a number?  What about the line above it?

Comment: @selbie: That -E option will be excellent for the future. Thanks, and I appreciate your continued help on this matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between `#define ASMJIT_API` and `-DASMJIT_API`.

The `#define` statement defines `ASMJIT_API` as nothing, while [the `-D` flag defines the preprocessor constant as `1`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html).

Using the `-D` flag, line 274 of build.h expands to

```
1 void assertionFailure(const char* file, int line, const char* exp);
```

causing the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't insert a space between -D and ASMJIT_API.  Ditto for -I

```
CFLAGS = -DASMJIT_API -Idep/
```

There you go.

Comment: @kisplit - When you type "make test", do you see the -DASMJIT_API as part of the generated command line?